# Subversion Authorization specifics

Tags: svn, authorization

We have a group of 300 developers. All of them will have rw access to one of the repos, but a small group of them - let's call them contractors -  should not be allowed to read any other repo but that one.
If I am to understand path based authorization correctly we are going to have to include all developers except for the contractors in the AuthzSVNAccessFile and place them in a group. Then for each repo we distinctly define access for this group, and for the one repo that anyone can have access to, just use the * variable.
Our setup is Apache, mod_dav, svn.
Am I understanding correctly or is there a shorter way?

Comment: Consider moving to VisualSVN Server. VisualSVN Server Standard Edition (free one) supports authorization rules based on Active Directory group accounts: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/screenshots/screenshot2.png.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pretty much - in the authorization file you unfortunately can't do something like utilize an LDAP group.

For your sanity, you might consider automatically generating the authorization file via a configuration management tool's template system, depending on how you're currently managing the user accounts.

Comment: User accounts are in AD :/